# Notepad++ path environment variable

Tags: path, notepad++, development-environment

I added C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++ to my Path environment variable. I've since tried launching the notepad++.exe from PowerShell, but it isn't recognised. I've tried this with quotes in the Path, without, tried restarting PowerShell, tried a full restart of the PC..

Has anyone succesfully launched notepad++ with it in Path?

Answer (score 0):

you could try start notepad++ in powershell or just hit winkey+r, type notepad++ in run command. both will open notepad++

Answer (score -1):

@MaxRussell

> *I've tried this with quotes in the Path, without, tried restarting PowerShell*

There is no need to put quote in path value of notepad++ install directory. it is enough to restart the PowerShell/cmd.exe to run notepad++. After that just type notepad++ *file_name.extention*

Comment: They already tried with and without quotes.